# How to connect SignalR Server hosted on ASP.net MVC website to JAVA Swings Software Client

Tags: java, asp.net-mvc, swing, signalr

I have a SignalR server hosted on ASP.net MVC website, and my .net Winforms Applications connect easily to it.

I want a JAVA Swings Application also to be connected as a Client to this Server.
I searched for it but everywhere all examples provide code for Android only. For example this [link](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/signalr/java-client/sample).

So how can I do this?

Comment: you should have to look into this, it seems you require some kind of request broker object to connect two different applications, please go through this once, hope it will help https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/rmi-corba-136641.html

Comment: But those are seems to legacy, I recommended you to go for Apache Thrift https://thrift.apache.org/